# flink checkpointing failing because of jdbc write backpressure

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a flink application which queries the database for every 30 min, do some transformations and persist into database. I am trying to process 100k records, because of backpressure from jdbc write task, database querying task and one of transformation task is not getting checkpointed and timing out. Enabling unaligned checkpoints also doesn't work. Using flink version 1.14.5, parallelism 15.

task manager config:

```
  taskmanager.memory.network.min: 128MB
  taskmanager.memory.network.max: 128MB
  taskmanager.memory.managed.size: 128MB
  taskmanager.memory.task.heap.size: 768MB
  taskmanager.memory.jvm-overhead.max: 256MB
  taskmanager.memory.jvm-overhead.min: 256MB
  taskmanager.memory.jvm-metaspace.size: 256MB
  taskmanager.memory.framework.off-heap.size: 128MB
  taskmanager.memory.framework.heap.size: 128MB
  taskmanager.memory.task.off-heap.size: 256MB
```

checkpointing config:
[image]
checkpoint latency
[image]

checkpoint status task by task
[image]
Execution flow
[image]

Even with 10k records also, I am seeing this issue. missing something here?

Another flink application has solace as input source and the same jdbc write task. This is working fine even with unaligned checkpoints disabled and same flink configuration.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If the JDBC database is the bottleneck, maybe it is under-provisioned.

Ideally the database query should be done asynchronously so that the task involved won't be blocked on i/o. You can do this with Flink's [async i/o operator](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/operators/asyncio/), or with a Flink SQL [lookup join](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/joins/#lookup-join). Changing that could help.

A better approach might be to convert the job to be based on CDC. This more decoupled, purely streaming architecture is a better fit for Flink.

Comment: update the question with checkpoint status by each task, some tasks are checkpointed even with 100% backpressure, may be backpressure is not the problem?